# Display 2 ArrayLists in HTML table

Tags: jakarta-ee, arraylist, html-table

I need some help with my school project.

I have 2 ArrayLists of object. One is with Student objects, one is with Course objects.

Each ArrayList contains actually a table from the DB(teacher said to do as so).

```
One table is Student(student_id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR,  year INT), one table is Course (course_id INT PRIMARY KEY, title VARHAR).
```

I need to display the 2 tables(the 2 ArrayLists) in a HTML table.

This code returns only the table header.

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="8" bgcolor= #EBDDE2> 
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor= #FF9966><b>ID</b></td>
                    <td bgcolor= #FF9966><b>Title</b></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td bgcolor= #FF9966><b>ID</b></td>
                    <td bgcolor= #FF9966><b>Name</b></td>
                    <td bgcolor= #FF9966><b>Year</b></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                   <% for (Course cs : courses){%>

                        <td><%= cs.getCourse_id() %></td>
                        <td><%= cs.getTitle() %></td>
                        <td></td>
                   <%}%>

                     <% for (Student st : students){ %>

                        <td><%= st.getStudent_id() %></td> 
                        <td><%= st.getName() %></td> 
                        <td><%= st.getYear() %></td>    
                </tr>

                      <%}%> 
                 </table>

              </body>
```

Comment: I am assuming you are using Java EE, is this correct?  First of all, under the afore asumption, I would make a custom tag to display both of the lists.  If your teacher isn't teaching you custom tags with Java EE he isn't teaching you correctly.  A good tutorial on this is http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html.  I know that this isn't a full solution but it should get you started.  If you want to do things the cheap way, the for loops you have should be more or less ok.... What does firebug say that the html is?

Comment: Yes, I use EE. I read in the link you posted. I'm using Java for resources. There I have methods that access the DB, make connection,... and I call them in JSP. Teacher said so:p

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
<table>
                   <tr>
                      <td>
                         <select id = "mySelect" multiple name = "sid" size = "5">
                             <% for (Student st : students){%>
                                   <option value="<%= st.getStudent_id() %>"><%= st.getStudent_id() %></option>
                                <%}%>
                         </select>                

                       </td>

                       <td><input type="submit" value = "Link"/></td>

                       <td>
                          <select  multiple name = "cid" size = "5">
                              <% for (Course cs : courses){%>
                                    <option value="<%= cs.getCourse_id() %>"><%= cs.getCourse_id() %></option>
                               <%}%>
                          </select>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                 </table>
```